# Flash Samsung Rugby Smart AT&T to factory conditions after installing cyanogenmod

Tags: cyanogenmod, rom, samsung, att

I have tried installing Cyanogenmod 10 on my Samsung Rugby Smart AT&T, but now I want to revert back to my old factory ROM. But how?

Comment: Did you make a Nandroid backup before flashing CM?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a Nandroid backup, you'll have to find a stock ROM for your device. Your device is not that well-known, the only resource I could find is on [XDA-Developers](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1838435). There you can find information on how to use ODIN to flash a stock ROM (post #5).

In the future, creating a Nandroid backup is always recommended before flashing a ROM, just in case something happens or you want to go back.

Comment: thanks for your comprehensive answer, I would try this solution and tell about my experience here.

Comment: When looking for ROMs, a good place to start is our question [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/16575) and its answers :)

Comment: @Izzy: I almost know that, but problem is a little different and complicated about Samsung Rugby Smart and the AT&T. That's why I open a new thread

Comment: @MaziarBouali That was perfectly fine and absolutely correct -- my intention was not telling you "please ask there", we are not a "forum" :) Just wanted to give you the *ressource* to check, in case the XDA thread fails :)

Comment: @Izzy: yup :) I got it and I'm so grateful for your sense of duty about keeping "StackExchange" family disciplined. Thanks. :)